# Constructor for class with readonly field of immutable storage

Tags: c#, immutable-collections

Let's say we have the following simple class. Note that the only field is `readonly` and is for an `ImmutableList<int>`:

```
class Abc
{
    readonly ImmutableList<int> elts;

    public Abc(params int[] ls) => elts = ImmutableList.CreateRange(ls);
}
```

Given the constructor shown, it's pretty easy to create an instance from some `int`s:

```
var result_a = new Abc(10, 20, 30);
```

Now, I may also want a constructor that can build an `Abc` given an `IEnumerable<int>`:

```
public Abc(IEnumerable<int> ls) => elts = ImmutableList.CreateRange(ls);
```

So our class now looks like this:

```
class Abc
{
    readonly ImmutableList<int> elts;

    public Abc(params int[] ls) => elts = ImmutableList.CreateRange(ls);

    public Abc(IEnumerable<int> ls) => elts = ImmutableList.CreateRange(ls);
}
```

This does indeed work:

```
var ls = new[] { 10, 20, 30 };

var result_b = new Abc(ls);
```

However, this constructor is a bit awkward because at first glance, something like this:

```
new Abc(item)
```

may look like it's creating an `Abc` with a single element (`item`). But if `item` is actually an `IEnumerable<int>` with more than one item, second constructor above will be called.

If you look at the Microsoft `ImmutableList` API, they actually have static method called [`ImmutableList.CreateRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable.immutablelist.createrange?view=netcore-2.2#System_Collections_Immutable_ImmutableList_CreateRange__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__) which is similar to the second constructor above. This is nice because we avoid the visual ambiguity described above.

OK, so let's start to sketch out a naive implementation of a similar constructor for our `Abc` class:

```
public static Abc CreateRange(IEnumerable<int> ls)
{
    elts = ImmutableList.CreateRange(ls);

    ...
}
```

Of course, we run into an issue here because the `elts` field is `readonly` and cannot be initialized via this static method:

[image]

So, what's a good approach for implementing `CreateRange` for our `Abc` class?

Comment: Make it call a (private?) constructor.

Comment: @SLaks Thanks for the suggestion! It looks like John provided an answer based on your suggestion. Looks good!

Comment: if `elts` is already private, why do you also make it readonly?

Comment: @shingo If nothing else, it's a good way to tell future maintainers that even code in the `Abc` class shouldn't replace `elts` after the class has been constructed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe SLaks' suggestion is to create a private constructor and call that from the static method:

```
private Abc(IEnumerable<int> ls) => elts = ImmutableList.CreateRange(ls);

public static Abc CreateRange(IEnumerable<int> ls) => new Abc(ls);
```

That way the only way (without reflection) to create an instance of `Abc` is to use the static method, assuming you don't have any public constructors.

Comment: Thanks John! That makes sense. I'll likely go with this approach.

Comment: @dharmatech I recommend accepting Strom's answer since it came first, is basically the same, and is more detailed :)

Answer (score 2):

The only way to set `elts` is to call a constructor for Abc.

The `readonly` modifier guarantees the only only way to set the variable is during initization, `readonly int i=0;` or in the constructor.

The error is cause by the static method not having access to an instance of `Abc`, although you would still not be able to modify it, since it is `readonly`.

Try this instead:

```
public static Abc CreateRange(IEnumerable<int> ls)
{
   return new Abc(ls);
}
```